# Recover of slave in MySQL Master-Master Replication

Tags: mysql, replication, master-slave

How can we recover slaves in case one master goes down in master-master replication while slaves are pointed to the master which got failed ?

Answer (score 0):

Here we have Master-Master Replication in MySQL and 3 slaves under one master and 1 slave under another master. Now what needs to be done if M1 goes down and we have to bring 3 slaves under M2.

M1--S1,S2,S3
M2--S4

M1 : Master1
M2 : Master2

S1,S2 and S3: Slaves configured under M1

Scenario : M1 goes down (Server is not accessible) and traffic is being served by M2 now we have to bring S1,S2 and S3 under M2

1. On M2
   a. show slave status (note down the positions)
   b. Parse current binlog and check what is last command logged with server id of M1 after that all commands must be logged using M2 server id
   c. Note down the position just after the last command logged by M1 server id
2. Check all slaves S1,S2,S3 should be having same show slave status status as M2 if not try making them read relay logs if available by starting SQL thread
3. Once all slaves are at the same position start all of the using position obtained in step 1(c.)
4. Now all three slaves are under M2 without any data loss

Note : In this case if M1 is not in sync with M2 and even relay logs on M2 is not available there would be data loss and slaves may throw some errors as well